# FlinkScalaKryoInstantiator not found exception on upgrade the flink version to 1.16.2

Tags: java, serialization, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am working on apache flink for streaming the data. Earlier I used the version flink 1.13.16 and recently upgrade the version to flink 1.16.2. Now I am getting exception
*e.g.

12:38:38.845 [main] INFO org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializer - Kryo serializer scala extensions are not available.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.runtime.types.FlinkScalaKryoInstantiator
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializer.getKryoInstance(KryoSerializer.java:486)
at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializer.checkKryoInitialized(KryoSerializer.java:521)
at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializer.copy(KryoSerializer.java:306)
at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.PojoSerializer.copy(PojoSerializer.java:250)
at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.PojoSerializer.copy(PojoSerializer.java:250)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.AbstractStreamOperatorTestHarness$MockOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperatorTestHarness.java:846)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.AbstractStreamOperatorTestHarness$MockOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperatorTestHarness.java:807)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:56)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:29)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.TimestampedCollector.collect(TimestampedCollector.java:51)
at com.abp.accountstatements.projections.PcBasedOnCalendarChange.processElement(PcBasedOnCalendarChange.java:59)*

Here is code

```
/****** PcBasedOnCalendarChange.java *******/
public class PcBasedOnCalendarChange
    extends KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction<
    String, GenerationDetail, String, GenerationDetail> {

   .....
   .....

  @Override
  public void processElement(
      GenerationDetail genDetail,
      ReadOnlyContext ctx,
      Collector<GenerationDetail> collector)
      throws Exception {
    try {
      String accNum = genDetail.getAccount().getAccountNumber();

      statementGenDateState.update(genDetail);
      collector.collect(genDetail); // It gives above exception on upgrade the flink version to 1.16.2
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error(e.getMessage());
      ctx.output(OutputExceptions.statementGenerationDetailOutput, genDetail);
    }
  }
  .....
}

/****** GenerationDetail.java *******/
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class GenerationDetail {
  private String accountId;

  private AccountIdentifier account; // AccountIdentifier is serializable class

  private BusinessDateDTO accOpeningDate; // BusinessDateDTO is serializable class

  private String generateFrequency;

  private String contractId;

  private String productId;

  private String calendarCode;

  private Frequency frequency; // Frequency is serializable class
}
```

Package "org.apache.flink.runtime.type" is deleted from flink version 1.14.0 onwards.

Can you please help me to resolve this issue?

I tried to to resolve issues by setting different serializer but it's not working. Here are links which I followed to resolved the issue but not working.

- https://flink.apache.org/2020/04/15/flink-serialization-tuning-vol.-1-choosing-your-serializer-if-you-can/
- https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/serialization/third_party_serializers/

Comment: Have you checked the release notes for 1.14 and accounted for the changed dependency names? https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/release-notes/flink-1.14/#summary-of-changed-dependency-names

Comment: @MartijnVisser Thank you for response. I did that and compilation is successfully but it gives issue during runtime like in description.